# Heroku Rails app v 1.2.6 failed to push: unrecognized error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I get this error when trying to push a Rails app v. 1.2.6 to Heroku:

```
 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persist
s.


To git@heroku.com:myproject.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myproject.git'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support Rails below 2.0. It might be painful but if you want to stay with Heroku you'd have to upgrade to at least Rails 2.3.5.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails

Comment: What about "Rails 2.3.5 and earlier should work on any of the Heroku stacks." ?

Comment: "Heroku supports all versions of Rails from 2.0 through 3.0.x" and http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2008/1/2/rails_12_deprecated/ unfortunately 3.5 years is a long time in Rails land. 1.2.6 also has some security vulnerabilities http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4954/product_id-8446/version_id-65467/Ruby-On-Rails-Ruby-On-Rails-1.2.6.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's your gemfile. If your are using `sqlite3`, change the line `gem sqlite3` to `gem pg`.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3